# When not "all" neither "some" is stated, what is implied?

Tags: ambiguity

For example, in sentence "Multinational companies are unethically exploiting the plant genetic resources of developing countries." is it implied that ALL multinational companies do that, or that SOME multinational companies do that?

My math teacher once told me, that in math "all" is always implied, and "some" is never implied, but I guess English rules may be different from math rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context usually indicates whether you should interpret it as some or all.  I think that it is reasonable to assume **some** in your sentence, as it would be difficult to collect sufficient evidence that all were doing it.

> Visitors to Indonesia must apply in advance for a visa and provide evidence of a recent health check.

In this sentence, we should assume **all**. It describes a law and, unless otherwise stated, laws apply equally to all people.

> Triangles have three sides

Like law, mathematics is logical, so it is generally reasonable to assume **all**.